# Euler diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

Hello every one I wanted to plot a Euler diagram, but what I am expecting to plot in a different way which is looking as below. how can I plot this type Euler diagram any suggestions, is it possible to plot like this

Thank you

```
  A  B  C  D   A1   B1   C1   D1
  2  3  5  6   2   30   30   60
  3  0  1  2   4   50   10   10
  4  0  6  5   85   4   85   50
  6  0  10 4   90  70   90    4
  5  92 50 10  50  50    3   30
```

[image]

Comment: did you look here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm.html ?

Comment: Okay I will edit my question

Comment: A problem is that circles are not in general adequate for expressing the relationships for more than 3 sets. For 4 sets a configuration using ovals is possible, Genuinely weird non-convex shapes are needed for anything beyond 4. If there is a special condition which the matrix satisfies (e.g. no number appears in more than 3 successive columns) it might help to spell that out.

Comment: The values which not common between A and A1, wanted check values  from A is in B, C, D same for A1 is in B1,C1, D1

Comment: A1 and B have values which are in common, but the circles in your diagram don't overlap. There are other instances of that between your data and your circles. The circles that you have drawn don't seem to clearly describe how the columns intersect. If it isn't column intersection that the diagram is designed to show, what is it supposed to show? Your last comment left me more confused rather than less confused.

Comment: @JohnColeman  Sorry, for the mistake I have edited my values if u see A&A1 common values are two values(2,4), rest values for A are 3,5,6 wanted see this values A&(B&C&D) same way wanted see for A1

Comment: There is a package for drawing Euler diagrams: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/eulerr.pdf. Perhaps that will help. Doing what you are trying to do would be highly non-trivial using just drawing primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you will not be able to express an arbitrary set of relationships for more than 3 sets with circles. The package `eulerr` uses ellipses to get more combinations and also make the result somewhat proportional to the number of elements in each region. I made a different package called `nVennR` that uses circles for the regions instead of the sets. The sets are then *drawn around* those circles:

```
> library(nVennR)
> myT <- read.table('clipboard', header = T)
> lol <- as.list(myT)
> myV <- plotVenn(lol)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
> myV <- showSVG(nVennObj = myV, opacity = 0.2)
```

Repeating the command `myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)` is necessary to get a compact shape. If you try it, you will see that it takes a couple of minutes, as it needs to perform several simulations. The package can take any number of sets, but things get really slow above 9 sets. The result:

[image: Euler diagram]

You can save, edit and improve the picture to better show the information, but it is not trivial. You can find more information in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html).